# mkinitcpio generation after update

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules, pacman

I updated the database `pacman -Syy` and update all packages `pacman -Su`. Then I checked the upgraded packages

```
cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep -i upgraded
[2017-07-14 14:21] [ALPM] upgraded linux (4.11.7-1 -> 4.11.9-1)
```

Somewhere during installation I read that probably I have to re-run `mkinitcpio -p linux` if the package was upgraded. Is it still relevant?

Comment: There is a hook that takes care of this automatically now (as of pacman 5.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the upstream kernel packages, and you haven't manually reconfigured pacman, then you shouldn't need to.

You can easily check though by seeing what the timestamp on /boot/initramfs-linux.img is, if it's newer than /boot/vmlinuz-linux.img, then the initramfs was updated, and you don't have to manually update it.